# Upgrade from ESXi 4.x to 5.0

Tags: esxi

I cannot find any clearly description about the upgrad from ESXi 4.x to ESXi 5.0. ( I can just found documents about the upgrades of vSphere, but I do not need them.) Does anybody knows a good document about the ESXi update?

Comment: This belongs in ServerFault instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just boot from the ESXi 5 installation CD, and make sure you pick the option to keep the existing datastores during installation (and make damn sure you have a good set of backups!)